# Fixing an IIS website using BizTalk WCF WebHttpWebServiceHostFactory

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

**Edit: fixed this problem. This ASP component was missing from IIS.**

I've recently inherited a BizTalk system and it's previously developer left next to nothing in the way of notes, and in several cases no project files. I have a dev and live machine.

The problem I have is that I have a system on the dev server that I'm trying to make live and I'm completely stuck on one thing: an IIS website on Dev which receives HL7 from an external source (another company). The URL of the website is connected to a receive port of Type WCF-WebHttp, which then passes the HL7 onto various orchestrations. I can find no source code whatsoever for the IIS website. I have tried using IIS's Export Application function, and then importing it onto IIS on the live server but to no success.

The website URL is /HL7/ORU/R01/HTTPBasic/Service1.svc the file Service1.svc contains the following code

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="c#" Factory="Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WebHttpWebServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
```

When I try to test the port locally, using Postman, I receive the following error:

> HTTP Error 500.0 - System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException
>   The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

When I look in the logs I see the following error:

> WebHost failed to process a request.
>    Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/12036987
>    Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/HL7/ORU/R01/HTTPBasic/Service1.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Receive location for address "/HL7/ORU/R01/HTTPBasic/Service1.svc" not found. (The BizTalk receive location may be disabled.). ---> Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.AdapterException: Receive location for address "/HL7/ORU/R01/HTTPBasic/Service1.svc" not found. (The BizTalk receive location may be disabled.)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.ReceiveLocationManager`2.GetEndpointContext(Uri uri)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WebServiceHostFactory`3.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
>      at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>      at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>      at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>      at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>    Process Name: w3wp
>    Process ID: 17092

This  tells me that

> The service '/HL7/ORU/R01/HTTPBasic/Service1.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.

As far I can see both servers appear to match one another in terms of installed software and versions of that software. The website is working correctly and the receive location is not disabled

Can anyone help?

*Edit: Added more detail*

Comment: And the URI in the receive location matches exactly?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Yes it does. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: What happens if you just browse to the web service?  The "exception during compilation" indicates that there may be something miss-configured in the web service.

Comment: Ah! Yes, there is something missing. The ASP component is missing from IIS, hence the compilation error! That fixed it!

Comment: Please post your fix as an answer, rather than an edit of the question. :-)

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I have done that, thanks for reminding me and once again thanks for taking the time to post :)

Answer (score 0):

It was all a mistake on my part. The ASP component of IIS was missing. Installing that fixed everything.